# Form Validation - Modify Second Parameter in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Is it possible to modify the second parameter for a custom callback?

```
<pre>
<code>

$something = 14 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'callback_valid_name['.$something.']'); 
public function valid_name($value, $something) {
$something = 20

 } 
 </code>
</pre>
```

Say I want to pass something to a custom callback. For example, I pass `$something` and it is equal to 14. After it gets passed and the callback function returns, `$something` is no equal to 20. Does that make sense?

I am not having any luck with this so far.

Comment: could you be more clear, as what are you trying to achieve..!

Comment: @ShatheeRuhunnabi set_rules passes the name value to the callback function. You could define the "something" variable as a class variable and thus you have access to it from all the methods in the class.

Answer (score 3):

**set_rules** passes the **name** value to the callback function. You could define the **something** variable as a class variable and have access to it from all the methods in the class.